# undefined method `delayed_backend_active_record_job_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, nitrousio

I'm using the `delayed_job_active_record` gem on a Rails app. I've been following the documentation about implementing background tasks, but encountered the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Home#index

Showing /home/action/workspace/postagain/app/views/home/index.html where line #2 raised:

undefined method `delayed_backend_active_record_job_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004d9f928>:0x00000004d9e960>
```

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong.

Here's the `index.html` view code located in the `home` folder. The link triggers the background task:

```
<%= link_to "Scan Buffer posts", buffer_scan %>
```

This is the Home controller code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    helper_method :buffer_post
    helper_method :buffer_scan
  def index
  end
  def buffer_post(profile_ids, text)
    client = Buff::Client.new(Figaro.env.buffer_access_token)
    client.create_update(options = {body: {profile_ids: profile_ids, text: text}})
  end
  def buffer_scan
    Delayed::Job.enqueue BufferPostsUpdate.new("test")
  end
end
```

This is the custom job located in the apps/jobs folder:

```
BufferPostsUpdate = Struct.new(:test) do
    def perform
      puts "test"
    end
end
```

Can't figure out what's wrong. Googling didn't turn out anything useful. Not sure if this helps, but I'm using Nitrous, an IDE based in the cloud, to run the development server. Any help is appreciated!

Here's the full stack trace:

```
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:129:in `polymorphic_url'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:135:in `polymorphic_path'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:87:in `url_for'
turbolinks (2.2.1) lib/turbolinks/xhr_url_for.rb:12:in `url_for_with_xhr_referer'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:180:in `link_to'
app/views/home/index.html:2:in `_app_views_home_index_html___3533284595993493556_40793080'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__4369149141656021554__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.7.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2120319930356218698__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link_to` call needs to point to a route/controller action as the second argument, and that controller action is where you need to enqueue the background task. You can't link directly to the background task.

You should remove the `helper_method :buffer_scan` line and change the `buffer_scan` method to look more like a controller action:

```
def buffer_scan
    Delayed::Job.enqueue BufferPostsUpdate.new("test")
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Make sure you add a route for the `buffer_scan` action, then your `link_to` should look like:

```
<%= link_to "Scan Buffer posts", buffer_scan_path %>
```

Now when you click the link, you'll hit the `buffer_scan` action, which will enqueue the update, then redirect the user back to your homepage.